# Отладка эксплуатации уязвимости

Tags: отладка, уязвимости, reverse-engineering

Исследую уязвимость ворда cve-2014-1761. Сгенерировал metasploit'ом вредоносный rtf-файл, при открытии которого отрабатывает полезная нагрузка, предоставляющая серверу доступ к командной строке компа, на котором был открыт файл. В чем проблема. Пытаюсь запустить под отладчиком. Хочу посмотреть где и что переполняет и т.п. Сама полезная нагрузка не так интересна, как непосредственно эксплуатация уязвимости (переполнение). Суть в том, что эксплойт отрабатывает только тогда, когда запускаешь сам rtf файл (при открытии из ворда, ничего не происходит). То есть открыть отладчиком winword.exe, а уже потом из него открыть rtf файл нельзя. Соответственно я не знаю, каким образом подключиться к процессу, до начала переполнения. Есть идеи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Патчите точку входа у winword: старый байт записываете на бумажку (скорее всего 0x55), вместо него - 0xCC. Жмакаете по RTF и при запуске winword срабатывает INT3. Если настроен Just-in-Time debugger - предложат им подцепиться к процессу. После этого патчите точку входа обратно, меняете EIP и радостно отлаживаете.

Comment: @tiigg Я думал столь очевидный способ вы уже испробовали...